# Rollmean vs. Integrate.xy for computing Integrals

Tags: r, p-value, numerical-integration

I have a density function in R that reflects an underlying null distribution, for example:

```
 density_null=density(rnorm(100))
```

I want to integrate between 0 and some point. Using the package integrate.xy, I get:

```
number=-1
library(sfsmisc)
pvalue=integrate.xy(density_null$x,density_null$y,min(density_null$x),number)
#pvalue=.0301
```

However when I use the rollMean package for integrating:

```
library(zoo)
Avg.pos <- number;xt <- diff(density_null$x[density_null$x<Avg.pos]);yt <- rollmean(density_null$y[density_null$x<Avg.pos],2);
pvalue=sum(xt*yt)
#pvalue=.028
```

Thus, my question is: **Which of these two methods is better for integration of density plots?** I realize the difference is small, but my this is leading to a significant difference down the analysis pipeline I am doing that is sensitive to pvalue changes. Also, my actual data is not really a normal distribution, but is a density distribution derived from other data, so analytical methods for hypothesis testing relying on properties of distributions will not work.

Comment: It depends on how your density distribution was "derived."  If, as suggested in the first line, it is the density evaluated on a *random sample* of values, then the running arithmetic mean has desirable properties.  But if for any reason those values are not randomly sampled, then the running arithmetic mean may be grievously in error.

Answer (score 0):

Rollmean appears to be better I benchmarked this for normal distributions at least. This benchmark does 1000 integrations, where each distribution had 10,000 points. As a true value, I simply take the number of points below the number.
 bench_mark=data.frame()

```
bench_mark=data.frame()

for (i in 1:1000){
    nums=rnorm(10000)
    density_null=density(nums)
     #Get random number
    number=runif(1,-1,-.5)
    z=length(nums[nums <=number]);true_integral=z/length(nums)

library(sfsmisc)
pvalue_integrate_xy=integrate.xy(density_null$x,density_null$y,min(density_null$x),number)
 library(zoo)
 Avg.pos <- number;xt <- diff(density_null$x[density_null$x<Avg.pos]);yt <- rollmean(density_null$y[density_null$x<Avg.pos],2);
pvalue_rollmean=sum(xt*yt)
bench_mark[i,1]=true_integral 
bench_mark[i,2]=pvalue_integrate_xy
bench_mark[i,3]=pvalue_rollmean
message(i)}
#benchmark using root mean squared error
library(Metrics)
rmse(bench_mark[,1],bench_mark[,2])
rmse(bench_mark[,1],bench_mark[,3])
```

The third column (i.e. rollMean) has an RMSE of about 0.0019, while integrate.xy has an RMSE of .0026.